# ERROR: could not read block 240030 in file "pg_tblspc/16387/PG_9.1_201105231/16388/16597.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, corruption

My friend got the following error So I imported his idb_dumps into my system.

**ERROR:  could not read block 240030 in file "pg_tblspc/16387/PG_9.1_201105231/16388/16597.1": read only 0 of 8192 bytes.**

In pgadmin3 I ran the following query
**"select n.nspname AS tableschema, c.relname AS tablename, c.relfilenode as rel_file_node from pg_class c
inner join pg_namespace n on (c.relnamespace = n.oid) ORDER BY rel_file_node;"**

But in the output, I am not seeing any entry for  "relfilenode = 16597.1"

Please help me to find corrupted table or index.

one more thing why relfilenode is float value?

Comment: How exactly did you "import" the data? That is not a floating point number, it is the second 1GB segment of a table file. Omit the `.1` suffix for your query.

Comment: my friend helped in importing using the pg_dump tool. Yes, I tried with omitting .1 also. Is my database corrupted? Any way to fix this? Maybe you know some different approach?

Comment: Yes that is data corruption, and you should restore from a backup. The point is that PostgreSQL is not in the habit os corrupting data unless there are hardware problems or you messed with the catalogs or the data files. In response to which statement do you get that error? Please copy and paste the actual command, not type it by hand as you did in your question (that statement would throw an error).

Comment: The important thing is to figure out what went wrong so you can avoid that in the future.

Comment: I have table corresponding to 16597. Now how to fix this table? I am able to manage this by doing file copy of database not dump one.

Comment: You cannot do "file copy", you have to restore a proper database backup. If you have no backup, you'll lose data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above query from question won't work until you are not copying the entire database from other systems. Here dump of database files doesn't help which I have tried earlier.